# Getting Permission Denied for read and write

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I got my app working with read and write with wide-open permissions and now I'm locking it down. My app won't read or write though. I get permission denied errors despite the Firebase rules simulator saying that my rules are ok for a Facebook authenticated user whose UID I got from a successful firebase `signInWithProvider`. What am I missing?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "items": {
      "$uid": {
        // user must match the authenticated user
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my data structure:

```
my-firebase-app
    -items: {
        -<uid123> : [
            {label:'apple'},
            {label:'banana'}
        ]
        -<uid456> : [
            {label:'pear'},
            {label:'cherry'}
        ]
    }
```

- I sign into firebase after facebook auth by doing, `firestack.auth.signInWithProvider(provider, facebookAccessToken, '')`, which gives me my user object including uid
- I push to `/items/uid123` and get an item id, `333`
- I set the item `{label:'apple'}` for the new ID (333) at `/items/uid123/333`
- I subscribe to the collection of items at `/items/uid123` by doing this with the web sdk: `itemsRef.child(uid).on('value', (snapshot) => .....`

My set call looks like,

`const  newPostRef = itemsRef.child(uid).push();
newPostRef.set(itemWithID)`

`set` promise gets rejected with permission denied error.

All the things above work fine if my `.read` and `.write` are simply set to `true` which leads me to think my syntax or structure is just off in the rules def. Would love some input.

Comment: Please share the minimal code that triggers the problem.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen, I've updated my question with more detail

Comment: I still don't understand which code triggers the problem. Is it the `on()` that triggers the `permission denied`? Also note that we have no way to see how the auth flows here. Instead of a bullet list of how you think it executes, share a [single snippet that (when run) triggers the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It may help if you try to reproduce the problem in a jsbin (although that would mean having to reproduce without firestack).

Comment: Thanks, this is react native so it won't work in a jsbin. I'm using react-native-firestack for auth, which succeeds – I get my user object back and contains a `uid` field whose value is what I'm using in place of `uid456` above. I'm using the firestack web sdk for the other methods. My `on` doesn't throw an error, just doesn't fire. My `set` call (added above) does trigger the error though – again, only when my rules are not wide open and set to `true`. Doesn't seem likely that it's my JS since it works without db rule constraints? Does my rules def look correct relative to the db structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the security rules, and in theory, both the set and the query operations look fine.

In practice however, you are making a grave mistake. As you revealed in the comments, you are trying to use both the Web SDK and the react-native-firestack library at the same time!

The authentication state is not shared between the two, thus the `on('value')` query is completely unauthenticated. If you added the third parameter to `on` (the cancel callback), you would see the permission denied error.

You must eliminate the web SDK completely, and use the realtime database via firestack too.

Comment: That was it, it's all working now that I migrated every Firebase action to firestack. Thanks!